# Google Sheet End Of The Month Date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using a google sheet for daily task tracking, we enter the date in column A and then task detains in other columns. I want to restrict data entry in this sheet on the last day of every month i.e. In column A I want to restriction entries if the date entered in that cell is after 29th of the respective month. Check the below link for more explanation.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NH2-wadJOCruW9z0G9s-03XLfvVNw-MQdnvEgFAGRuk/edit?usp=sharing

Any help on above will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: It is not clear whether a restriction is required after 29 or the last two days?

Comment: After 29th.....

Answer (score 0):

**Data validation - formula**

```
=DAY(A1+2)>2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, however, when I apply this to data validation, then the cell validation as date is removed and hence the option of date selection via calendar is not available. Is there any way to apply the date restriction as well as allow date selection via calendar?

Comment: You may need a script to do that.